# query to new google spreadsheets

Tags: google-visualization, google-sheets

I created a line chart using google visualization.
The code queries a google spreadsheet.
When I use a normal spreadsheet (line 1), it works.
When I use a new google spreadsheet (URL on line 2) I have this error:

`Error in query: request time out`

I have the following two queries with two different URL: the first working, the second no.

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0AgtmZPWzQ7lldEt2S2VLajBRQVNFLV9pRFY2bTRQLVE&transpose=0&headers=1&merge=COLS&range=E2%3AE64%2CF2%3AJ64&gid=0&pub=1', opts);          
var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=1chFDkz5Fqus1ODgtdEGNt4Mq2nxnkKnuqbEB4LaZF6o&transpose=0&headers=1&merge=COLS&range=A1%3AA100%2CB1%3AF100&gid=0&pub=1', opts);
```

I played with the URL to find the right format. I am wondering if I cannot find the right format, or if the new google sheets do not work or work differently with queries.
If I just put the URL in a browser:

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=1chFDkz5Fqus1ODgtdEGNt4Mq2nxnkKnuqbEB4LaZF6o
```

It says the file does not exist (in the second case only, with the new google sheet)
This is the link to the spreadsheet:
[new google spreadsheet (second one)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1chFDkz5Fqus1ODgtdEGNt4Mq2nxnkKnuqbEB4LaZF6o/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The new spreadsheets are mapping the URL `http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=1chFDkz5Fqus1ODgtdEGNt4Mq2nxnkKnuqbEB4LaZF6o` to `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1chFDkz5Fqus1ODgtdEGNt4Mq2nxnkKnuqbEB4LaZF6o/tq?pub=1&tqx=reqId:0`, which returns a 404 error.  I filed a bug report on this [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1476).

Comment: I have the same problem: old spreadsheet OK, new spreadsheet 404. thanks asgallant for the bug report.

Answer (score 4):

It seems one possible solution (from a google spreadsheet project team member) is to use:
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq"

Basically, use "docs" instead of "spreadsheets" and add "/gviz/tq" to the end.
In my example, that would be:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1chFDkz5Fqus1ODgtdEGNt4Mq2nxnkKnuqbEB4LaZF6o/gviz/tq

Comment: and how to convert that into html output? simple adding "&tqx=out:html" to the query doesn't work anymore...

Comment: @Leszek: It works. Try: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1chFDkz5Fqus1ODgtdEGNt4Mq2nxnkKnuqbEB4LaZF6o/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html

`tql=out:html` is a query and is a part of transaction query `tq`. So, you must add all the queries after `tq?` for GViz to work accordingly.